# How do you set the last 'div' in another 'div' at the end flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do you set the last 'div' in another 'div' at the end with the changing number of elements in pagination? I have 12 elements.
During pagination, I have set the number of items for example 5 when I'm on the first page. Go to the second page I have 5 elements. Go to the third page I have two elements and here is the problem because

```
<div class =" pagination ">
    <ul uib-pagination>
    </ Ul>
</ div>
```

moves up, and I would like him to stay in the same place in down `<div class='Section'>`

```css
    .artistsSection {
      height: 100%; 
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }


    .pagination {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 10px;
      display: flex;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
 <div class='Section'>
        <h1>List </h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input />
        </div>

        <pre class="currentPage"></pre>
        <section class='todos'>
            <ul>
                <li >
                    <a></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <div class="pagination">
            <ul uib-pagination>
       
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I want to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for `align-self` on the main axis (like `justify-self`).

Instead, you could do something like:

```
.Section {
  height: 100%; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Should be: `.Section {
  height: 460px; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
 justify-content: space-between, align-items: center;`                                                                                                                                              
}  ` `.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
}`  It's work

Comment: Should still work, assuming you can squeeze your content into a fixed height.